# Project build succeeds but lots of errors appears when previewing

Tags: xcode, swiftui

My project builds fine, but when i build as previewing it shows lots of errors. Have already restarted my Mac and used pod install and pod update, but it still persists.

[image: 5th screenshot]

[image: pods]

The screenshot that shows an error in the code isthe only error that refers to some code, the other "red" errors don't refer to any fisic code

Edit: FAIL DIAGNOSIS:
umbrella header for module 'GoogleUtilities' does not include header 'GULSwizzler.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]

---

SchemeBuildError: Failed to build the scheme "MedicalApp"

umbrella header for module 'GoogleUtilities' does not include header 'GULSwizzler.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]

Build target FirebaseCoreDiagnostics:
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct pod is pod 'FirebaseCore', not pod 'Firebase/Core'. Try changing that pod and see if it works. Some of the "yellow" errors will remain, but the app should still build.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here as written :
**The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0**

Copy and paste this code to your podfile. After go to terminal and make `pod update`

```
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
      t.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
      end
    end
end
```